# Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Error initializing complex filters. Not yet implemented in FFmpeg, patches welcome

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I got this objective

> write a function in typescript which takes images array of type

```
interface Image {
    buffer: Buffer;
    start: number;
    end: number;
}
```

> and audio file of Buffer type, videoLength of type number.The function
> should use `fluent-ffmpeg` to create a video by combining these images
> based on their start and end time with a transition of fade filter.
> the audio should be placed on video. the code will be running on ab
> ubuntu linux distro. after the video generation is completed, saved
> the video in root directory of project.

```
import ffmpeg from "fluent-ffmpeg";
import * as fs from "fs";

interface Image {
    buffer: Buffer;
    start: number;
    end: number;
}

/**
 *
 * @param images contains the image buffers and their start and end times
 * @param audio  contains the audio buffer, save before use it
 * @param videoLength  contains the video length
 * @objective write a function in typescript which takes images array and audio file of Buffer type, videoLength of type number.
 * the function should use `fluent-ffmpeg` to create a video by combining these images
 * based on their start and end time with a transition of fade filter. the audio should be placed on video.
 * The code will be running on ab ubuntu linux distro. after the video generation is completed, saved the video in root directory of project.
 */

function createVideo(images: Image[], audio: Buffer, videoLength: number) {
    const command = ffmpeg();

    const audioPath = "audio.mp3";
    const durations: number[] = [];

    // Add images with start and end times
    images.forEach((image, index) => {
        const frameDuration = image.end - image.start; // Calculate duration of each frame
        durations.push(frameDuration);
        const imagePath = `image-${index}.png`;
        fs.writeFileSync(imagePath, image.buffer); // Create temporary image files from buffers

        command.input(imagePath).inputOptions(`-loop 1`).inputOptions(`-t ${frameDuration}`);
    });

    command.input(audioPath);

    fs.writeFileSync(audioPath, audio); // Create temporary audio file from buffer

    // Add audio
    command.input(audioPath).inputOptions(`-stream_loop -1`).inputOptions(`-t ${videoLength}`);

    // Add fade filter
    command.complexFilter([
        {
            filter: "fade",
            options: {
                enable: `'between(t,0,1)'`, // Notice the single quotes around the expression
                x: "810",
                y: "465",
            },
            inputs: `0:v`,
            outputs: `fade0`,
        },
        {
            filter: "fade",
            options: {
                enable: `'between(t,1,2)'`, // Notice the single quotes around the expression
                x: "810",
                y: "465",
            },
            inputs: `1:v`,
            outputs: `fade1`,
        },
        {
            filter: "fade",
            options: {
                enable: `'between(t,2,3)'`, // Notice the single quotes around the expression
                x: "810",
                y: "465",
            },
            inputs: `2:v`,
            outputs: `fade2`,
        },
    ]);


    // Add output options
    command.outputOptions([
        "-map [outv]",
        "-map [outa]",
        "-shortest",
    ]);

    // Add output file
    command.output("output.mp4");

    // Run ffmpeg
    command.run();

    // Delete temporary files
    // fs.unlinkSync(audioPath);
    // images.forEach((image, index) => {
    //     fs.unlinkSync(`image-${index}.png`);
    // });
}

export async function fluentFFmpeg() {
    try {
        // Usage example
        const images: Image[] = [
            { buffer: fs.readFileSync("image-0.png"), start: 0, end: 5 },
            { buffer: fs.readFileSync("image-1.png"), start: 6, end: 10 },
            { buffer: fs.readFileSync("image-2.png"), start: 11, end: 15 },
        ];

        const audioBuffer: Buffer = fs.readFileSync("audio.mp3");
        const videoLength: number = 15; // Duration of the resulting video
        const response = createVideo(images, audioBuffer, videoLength);
        console.log("response", response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    }
}
```